# ¿Cuál es la forma adecuada para que una función pueda reportar un error?

Tags: python, funciones

Hace no mucho, con idea de utilizarlo en una aplicación gráfica, hice un módulo para monitorizar ciertos valores del hardware a través de los sistemas de archivos proc y sys que Linux provee.

Como estos sistemas de archivos dependen en gran medida del hardware, sus controladores y de la versión de Linux, a veces se presentan errores tales como que un determinado archivo no es usado por un determinado dispositivo o es alojado en una ruta diferente o que la forma de dar la información es distinta.

Ante un error de este tipo, la duda que se me presenta es, descartando elevar una excepción, si lo correcto es devolver `None` ó `-1`.

Por ejemplo, por norma general, el valor em MHz de la frecuencia de cada procesador se haya en `/proc/cpuinfo` en las líneas que comienzan con `cpu MHZ` y el de la frecuencia máxima en `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policyX/cpuinfo_max_freq`. Puede ocurrir que con ciertos dispositivos (Raspberry y similares) en cpuinfo no aparezca `cpu MHZ` o que usando una distribución creada en VBox el directorio `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policyX/` sí exista pero no el archivo `cpuinfo_max_freq`. Si tengo 2 funciones que dan la frecuencia actual y la frecuencia máxima, ante alguno de los problemas arriba expuestos, ¿las funciones deberían retornar `None` o `-1`?

La duda es extrapolable a otras situaciones, funciones y lenguajes, así que me gustaría saber si existe algún tipo de convención que diga qué es lo correcto o qué es lo normativo.

Comment: Ok, gracias. ¿y si en vez de `int` es, como en este caso, `float`?. En estos caso descarté la elevación de excepciones porque, dado que los valores sí existen, la excepción sería algo como un ValueNotFoundError que tampoco aportaría nada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lenguajes primitivos como el C, que no disponía de excepciones, no hay mecanismo estandarizado de qué debe devolver una función en caso de error.

La biblioteca estándar C usa un convenio bastante consistente, que depende del tipo retornado por la función:

- Si retorna `int`, un -1 suele indicar error (digo "suele" porque tal vez -1 es una respuesta válida de la función, depende de lo que haga). Normalmente se usa en casos en que la función siempre retorna enteros positivos (como por ejemplo *handles* de ficheros, sockets, etc.) Técnicamente la función debería declarar su tipo de retorno como `unsigned int`, pero si así lo hiciera no podría retornar el -1 para indicar errores.
- Si retorna un puntero, el valor `NULL` (que es en realidad 0) indica un error.
- En funciones que retornen `double` o `float` el -1 no puede usarse porque típicamente se trata de funciones matemáticas para las que -1 es un posible resultado. Para estos casos `math.h` define constantes como `HUGE_VAL` (un valor muy grande, quizás infinito), o `NAN` (not-a-number). Pero tampoco está del todo claro cuál retornar. Para algunas funciones matemáticas retornar infinito no sería exactamente un error.

En cualquiera de los casos, el retorno de un "valor mágico" simplemente indica la existencia de un error, pero no informa de cuál ha sido en caso de que haya varias posibilidades. Para esto se tiene la variable global `errno` que contiene otro código numérico, o la función `perror()` para imprimir un mensaje adecuado (para lo que consulta `errno`).

Todo esto plantea múltiples problemas:

- La elección del valor mágico. Aunque la biblioteca estándar C es bastante consistente, otras bibliotecas no usan su convenio. Por ejemplo, las bibliotecas que implementan RPC (el clásico, y antiguo, ONC-RPC) no usan `errno` ni -1, sino otras constantes específicas.
- El cliente que hace la llamada está obligado a chequear el valor retornado. Si no lo hace asumirá que el -1 que ha recibido (o el valor que sea) es correcto y seguirá adelante con él, con resultados imprevisibles.
- El cliente que hace la llamada necesita además comparar el valor retornado (o la variable `errno`) con una serie de valores predefinidos para decidir cómo gestionar el error.

En el caso de Python tienes además que, al no existir el concepto de "tipo retornado por una función", sino simplemente "valor", puedes ampliar las posibilidades hasta hacerlas inmanejables. Por ejemplo, una función que "normalmente" retornaría enteros, puede elegir retornar `None` en caso de error. Esto evita el tener que reservar el valor -1 como especial, pero abre otra caja de Pandora. ¿Por qué `None`? Ya puestos podría retornar una cadena que dijera `"Error de rango"` o lo que se quiera. Estas cadenas tomarían el papel de `errno` a la hora de poder discernir entre diferentes errores.

Pero sería el caos.

Python tiene un mecanismo bien definido para reportar errores, y son las excepciones.

Cualquier lenguaje moderno tiene excepciones, por lo que no tiene ya sentido plantearse la devolución de "valores mágicos". Las excepciones resuelven muchos problemas:

- No interfieren con el tipo retornado por la función. Proporcionan otro "canal". La función tiene dos posibles salidas: la que devuelve con `return`, para la cual no habrá valores mágicos reservados, o la que devuelve con `raise()` que será siempre de otro tipo (`Exception`).
- Al ser las excepciones clases, puede haber una jerarquía de ellas, lo cual permite capturar a la vez todas las que sean de un mismo "tipo" (hereden de una misma clase base)
- Nos aseguramos de que el error no pasa desapercibido. Si el cliente que invocó la función no se ocupa de gestionar las excepciones, ésta se propagarán "hacia arriba" y acabarán por romper el programa, que siempre es mejor que dejarle seguir comportándose erráticamente.

En definitiva, por responder a tu pregunta final, yo diría: Si tu lenguaje tiene excepciones úsalas. Si no las tiene, estás en una fea situación pues no hay estándar y decidir adecuadamente es complicado, pero siempre puedes tomar como modelo lo que hace la biblioteca estándar C.

Comment: Al final, después de leer tu respuesta y meditarlo un poco, en este caso, he decidido hacer varias cosas: Como norma general, crear y elevar una excepción `ValueNotFoundError`. Como éste ha sido un módulo creado ex profeso para otra aplicación hecha por mí, no lo veía necesario, pero vendría bien para reutilizar el código después. En otras funciones, como las relacionadas con las baterías y SAI's conservaré el valor `None` en caso de que éstos no estén presentes o `inf` (esto no es un error en sí) en `remaining_time()` en caso de que sí estén presentes pero exista alimentación AC. Muy útil!